# How to find Latitude and longitude of current location of iphone using j2ee application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, latitude-longitude

I have a J2EE web based application which is especially developed for iPad, iPhone and other mobile devices. I need to find out the device current location longitude and latitude. 
I done this through javaScript navigator object like below.

var gps = navigator.geolocation;
if (gps){
    gps.getCurrentPosition(successFunction,errorFunction, options);
}

But its asking for user acceptance.
Is there any way to find out the current location details using java for web application.

Comment: it is asking for user acceptance so that you cannot spy on the user, that is the correct behavior

Answer (score 1):

As Aaron pointed out, if you want to get the **location from on-device GPS**, then you will have to accept the fact that the device will ask for user acceptance, no way around that.

**For mobile phones**, it is also possible to get the **approximate location from mobile network** (e.g. from [GMLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GMLC) over [MLP](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/M/Mobile_Location_Protocol.html)) but:

- you need **agreement with mobile operator** to provide access to such information (which you usually do not have)
- **it will not work for iPad**, as it is not connected to mobile network

Answer (score 1):

In a web application, you can use some web service to discover user's *approximate* location from their IP address. One such free service is http://freegeoip.appspot.com/. Its URL format is http://freegeoip.appspot.com/data-format/your-ip-address. For example, if you send an http request http://freegeoip.appspot.com/json/118.13.12.116, it will send you user's city, region, country, longitude and latitude in JSON format.